# Adding dynamic button to AccordionPane

Tags: vb.net

```
pane1.ID = "pane" & i
pane1.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(4).ToString() & " , "))
pane1.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(0).ToString() & " , "))
pane1.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(5).ToString()))
pane1.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(1).ToString() & " , "))
pane1.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(2).ToString() & " , "))

pane1.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(btn1)
```

Comment: Please describe what it is that you want answered (even if you expect someone who knows VB.net to understand just by looking at the code).

Comment: this is an Accordion ,,, the panes will display depended on ( i )

Comment: one of the column is an attachment  file

Comment: how i can call the attachment ... by using button "btn1" or something else